# Concise way to express the Spanish saying “it is preferable to be the head of a mouse than the tail of a lion”

Tags: idiom-requests, popular-refrains

I came across this vivid Spanish expression today and have been wondering how it might best be said in English:

"***Más vale ser cabeza de ratón, que cola de león***" which, literally, means that it is preferable to be the head of a mouse than the tail of a lion.

The sense of it is that it is preferable to be in charge of little things than to be an insignificant assistant in a grand enterprise.

Various related phrases come to mind. Few, for example, want to be a 'cog' in a machine. Some like to 'rule the roost'.

The closest I can think of is to say that '*it is better to be a big fish in a little pool rather than a little fish in a big pool'*.  Except that this seems to me only to be a contrived and laboured way of explaining the Spanish saying.  It does not have the ring or snap of the original.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The usual phrase is "better to be a big fish in a little pond" and leave it at that. The actual comparison doesn't need to be said.

Comment: Possibly this is more extreme than what you are looking for, but: "I'd rather reign in Hell than serve in Heaven."?

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Ye-es, except I can still hear a friend from years back saying how he was fed up of being a big fish in too little a pond.  Leaving aside his ego (!), the Spanish saying is unequivocally saying your suggestion, whereas the English fish/pond saying is more equivocal.

Comment: @Cascabel - I've not heard this before (just looked it up - Milton).  I like it and it feels close BUT neither Hell nor Heaven, in my mind at least, are ruled by 'mice'.

Comment: oofta! @Dan I think it is more from the bikie culture in the US..BTW...it's _león_  not _tigre_ ...It's gotta rhyme in Spanish. I think it translates better as the "least of two evils". After all, nobody wants to be a rat.

Comment: Thanks - yes I did see lion when I was looking it up.  The thing is that 'tigre' was the version I read (in a book by a Chilean friend).  But happy to go with the usual version.

Comment: Ok..I'm gonna go out  on a shaky timber and mention the joke from the "Master of the Seas"..."Doctor, when you examine the 2 weevils in this piece of bread..which do you prefer? " Why the largest, of course, Captain"..."Wrong!"

Comment: As an officer of HMS Navy...you must always choose ..." The lesser of two weevils!" Love that line.

Comment: Excellent pause (allowing time to wonder about the punch line)!

Comment: The phrase "unless you're the lead dog the view never changes..." states a similar idea but it's more related to leaders vs followers.

Comment: @Cascabel You mean the _Royal_ Navy! HMS means His/Her Majesty's _Ship_, not the service as a whole.

Comment: @KateBunting oops, my bad. I was USN. Should've  known better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found

> Better be the head of an ass than the tail of a horse

[here](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/m%C3%A1s-vale-ser-cabeza-de-rat%C3%B3n-que-cola-de-le%C3%B3n)

.

Comment: Thank you. It's a very good fit.

Answer (score 0):

to be Exact, This saying is from **Psalms** (book of the Bible)  King David ,written more than 2000 years ago. Its was then taken by the Spanish and others.

"it shall be better to be head of the wolfs then tail of the lion".

Comment: Interesting but not actually an answer to the question about a concise English equivalent.

Comment: Please provide a link or some information that would help people find that line in the source.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the actual idiomatic expression in English is somewhere along the lines of: it is better to be a Beggar among Kings than the king (of) among beggars

Comment: Isn't "it is better to be a Beggar among Kings than the king among beggars" the exact opposite of the Spanish saying?